# Where did file downloaded with PyQt5 network access manager go? And how do I save it?

Tags: qt, qt5, pyqt5, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

Without specifying file to save, I created this:

```
def start_download(self):
    self.reply = self.manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(self.url_edit.text())))
    self.reply.downloadProgress.connect(self.download_progress)
    self.label.setText(self.url_edit.text())

def download_progress(self, received, total):
    print(received, type(received))
```

The last function I mentioned did write received byte. So, the is downloaded. Where did it go without I specified path to save? And How can I save it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reply is a [QNetworkReply](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html), which is subclass of [QIODevice](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html). So, it is roughly equivalent to the file-like objects found in python.

Once the file has downloaded, you should be able to do something like:

```
    data = self.reply.readAll().data()
```

which will give you a python byte-string that can be saved to disk in the usual way.

Comment: So, is it not possible to pause the download and resume it?

Comment: @BagolDaplun. That has got nothing to do with the question that you asked, which was how to read and save the file.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, because you mentioned `readAll` which is called after the download finished, I got that pause and resume question. But, your answer fit this question, Thanks anyway ;). By the way, the `where did` part of my question still make me curious.